# Start a ripple effect on multiple items when there is a click on one of the

Tags: android

In my layout I have several TextView. When pressing on a particular TextView I would like the Ripple effect to happen on other specific TextView. How could I do this? So, how can you propagate a ripple effect on other views programmatically. Please help me, thank you in advance.